# How can I remove runtime dependencies from compiled jar

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

My Maven project, when built, produces a jar that is used by many applications in my org.  However, in one area, large jar file sizes causes deployment issues by timing out the connection, whereas small jars don't cause this issue.  For this one environment, I want to strip out several large runtime dependencies that are causing my jar size to be inflated, and have them be individually loaded at the deployment point.  Obviously I need these dependencies during compilation or it fails.

So my question is: is there a way to extract runtime dependencies from a compiled jar?

Comment: As with every other time I post a question to SE, I think I found my answer after a few more minutes of searching.  I can probably use the `scope` tag in Maven to exclude dependencies at runtime.  However, can I use this scope tag for transitive dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

By declaring the  `<scope>compile</scope>` that dependency will not be packed in the final jar. It will be used only for compilation.

More info could be found here [maven scope documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

As for your question about transitive dependencies, no it will not work. When those are imported by a parent dependency then using the scope those will be left out from jar also.

So you either declare them as standalone dependencies in pom or you provide them in runntime.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Keeping in line with my comment, I think I found a workaround for the transitive issue.  I'm excluding the worst offending transitive dependencies for pom dependencies, then I'm declaring those transitive dependencies at the pom level, and using the `provided` tag to declare that they will be available by the system at runtime.  Also, I think you mean to have `provided` instead of `compile`.  `compile` is the default behavior without declaring a scope